# jquery keyup, keydown doesn't work in table with multiple row

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup

I have a table which has 200 rows. Jquery keyup or keydown are not working. My jquery code is :

```
$('.upd_tab tbody tr td:eq(2) input').on('keyup',function(e){
        if (e.which==13)
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq($(this).parent().index()+1).find('input').focus();
    });
```

Actually I want to focus or go to the input box which is located in next td. This works with 1st tr but not in rest 199 trs
Here is the HTML.

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="chz1">
        <td><input maxlength="16"/><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><input/><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><input maxlength="6"/><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        <td><input value="1"/><div class="bx"><button class="sbut"></button></div><input type="hidden" class="hinp"/></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        <td><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><div class="bx"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="chz2">
        <td><input maxlength="16"/><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><input/><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><input maxlength="6"/><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        <td><input value="1"/><div class="bx"><button class="sbut"></button></div><input type="hidden" class="hinp"/></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        <td><div class="bx"></div></td>
        <td><div class="bx"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: Part of HTML code please.

Comment: I have tried with **.live** , **keypress** etc. But same problem exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `:eq(n)` selects the *nth* element from the previous selection. That is, the collection of all td's that are a child of a tr of a tbody of an element with the upd_tab class. It behaves basically like this: `$($('.upd_tab tbody tr td')[2])` (and the input below that element). If you would use `:eq(10)` it would select the input box on the second row.

What you want is `:nth-child(3)`.

```
$('.upd_tab tbody tr td:nth-child(3) input').on('keyup',function(e){
    if (e.which==13)
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq($(this).parent().index()+1).find('input').focus();
});
```

For an easier understanding what elements are being selected, consider colouring them, for example with `.css( { 'background': 'blue' } );`. This will give you a visual clue what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$('.upd_tab input').on('keyup',function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if (code == '13') {
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you **Jakub**. But I need to focus to the 1st input box at next tr when user press enter at the last input box( in last td). I also mention that there is two **<select>** box in every tr of this table, which I did not write here I want to focus next for those **<select>** too.